# Python, Correct way to formulate Binary Data ready to be sent over serial

Tags: python, serial-port, byte, bit

I am in need of creating a device which talks to a different device over serial. Pretty basic stuff.

However, All I need to do is pass down specific binary data and the device will handle the rest.

The data has to be in binary format and I have seen various way to do it across the internet but really unsure of what is the correct way of representing binary data and NOT a string.

Here are a few examples of what I found:

```
b'01001011' # Is this a packed string though?
bytes(4) # This creates bytes. How do I manipulate the bits?, is this data able to send over serial?
int('01001011', 2) # Will this be treated as an integer over serial?
binascii.hexify() # This produces ASCII representation
```

I need to formulate a few bytes of information which will involve me setting certain bits in each byte and I'm rather confused how to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary literals in python look like this:

```
>>> 0b11
3
>>> 0b10
2
>>> 0b100
4
```

you can manipulate bits using bitwise operators:

```
>>> 0b1000
8
>>> 0b1000 | 0b1
9
```

`|` is just the `or` operator. See other operators here: [BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

To see the numbers binary representation you can use string.format:

```
>>> "{0:b}".format(9)
'1001'
>>> "{0:b}".format(65)
'1000001'
>>> "{0:b}".format(234)
'11101010'
```

**EDIT**
Exemple of setting a particular bit:

```
# setting off second bit
>>> bin(0b1100 & 0b1011)
'0b1000'
# setting on third bit
>>> bin(0b1100 | 0b0010)
0b1110'
```

Note that binary literals give you a int:

```
>>> type(0b1)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Great stuff! One question, then, Is it possible to create say one byte of data `0b00000000'` and manipulate a specific bit? maybe by index? Also, what data type is this, is it just an int? or a bitarray?

Comment: its a number a (int). to manipulate bits you will have to dig in bitwise operations. I will put one example of a "bit affectation" in my answer.